# How to filter by more than one field in spring boot mongo repository

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I am really new to spring boot. I am creating a REST API that supports filtering with mongodb using mongo repository. Here is the code that I have done

```
@Document
public class Category {

    @Id
    String id;
    String name;
    String category;
    String iconName;

    public Category(String name, String category, String iconName) {
        this.name=name;
        this.category=category;
        this.iconName=iconName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public String getIconName() {
        return iconName;
    }
    public void setIconName(String iconName) {
        this.iconName = iconName;
    }


}
```

categoryRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends MongoRepository<Category,String> {
    Category filterByCategoryIcon(List<category,iconName>);
}
```

I want to filter a category by category and iconName.

Comment: ```filterByCategoryAndIconName(String category,String iconName) ``` is it not satisfying the requirement ?

Comment: Do you want to filter by a single category and iconName or by an array of them?

Comment: i want to filter by array of them.